# Problems with commit() function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to do a transaction with php and my sql with PDO, the thing is that when i use the commit() function, the code returns a "FALSE" echo, but insert the data anyway. Maybe im doing something wrong, my code is this:

In the Connection class

```
protected function getConexion()
{
    try 
    {
        $params = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true,PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"); 
        $this->conexion = new PDO($this->motor.":host=".self::$servidor.";dbname=".$this->db_name,self::$usuario,self::$password,$params);
        return $this->conexion;
    } 
    catch (PDOException $ex) 
    {
        echo "Error en la conexión : " . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and into my register function

```
if($miembro == "S")
    {
        try 
        {
            $this->getConexion()->beginTransaction();
            
            $sqlInsertUsuario = "INSERT INTO Usuario (apodo, password, correo, nombre, apellido, "
                    . "fchNacimiento, sexo, fchCreacion, ultimaSesion, ip, llave, activo, "
                    . "imgPerfil, nivel)"
                    . " VALUES (:apodo, :password, :correo, :nombre, :apellido, "
                    . ":fchNacimiento, :sexo, NOW(), NOW(), 'Ip aqui', :llave, '1', "
                    . "'imagen aqui', 'I')";
            $sqlInsertCandidato = "INSERT INTO Candidato (correo) VALUES (:correo)";
            
            $sentencia = $this->getConexion()->prepare($sqlInsertUsuario);
            $sentencia->execute(array(':apodo' => $apodo, ':password' => $clave, ':correo' => $correo,
                ':nombre' => $nombre, 'apellido' => $apellido, 'fchNacimiento' => date($fchNacimiento),
                ':sexo' => $sexo, ':llave' => $llave));
            
            $sentencia = $this->getConexion()->prepare($sqlInsertCandidato);
            $sentencia->execute(array(':correo' => $correo));
            
            $this->getConexion()->commit();
            
            echo 'TRUE';
        } 
        catch (Exception $ex) 
        {
            $this->getConexion()->rollBack();
            echo 'FALSE';
        }
    }
```

the problem is that returns "FALSE" but the data is inserted in the table anyway.

Comment: Have you checked what the actual exception is?? Currently your code just ignores the useful information from $ex (in the second snippet I mean)

Comment: write print_r($ex); in the catch to see which error you get

Comment: I get this message:

Stack trace:

#0 C:\wamp64\www\AsatruUruguayPrototipo\code\domain\Usuario.php(80): PDO->commit()
#1 C:\wamp64\www\AsatruUruguayPrototipo\code\logic\RegistrarUsuario.php(13): Usuario->registarUsuario('Olaf232', 'Santi123', 'sdasdfff32@blal...', 'undefined', 'undefined', '2021/1/1', 'N', 'S')
#2 {main}PDOException: There is no active transaction in C:\wamp64\www\AsatruUruguayPrototipo\code\domain\Usuario.php:80

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the thing is that I was calling the connection too many times in this method: `$this->getConexion()->beginTransaction();`

so the solution was to create a variable "$pdo" that saves the connection and later will use it for all the transaction.

```
$pdo = $this->getConexion();
$pdo->beginTransaction();
```

instead of this:

```
$sentencia = $this->getConexion()->prepare($sqlInsertUsuario);
$sentencia = $this->getConexion()->prepare($sqlInsertCandidato);
$this->getConexion()->commit();
```

use this:

```
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare($sqlInsertUsuario);
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare($sqlInsertCandidato);
$pdo->commit();
```